# Tcl - split a package into several files with dependencies between them

Tags: package, tcl

I'm a beginner on tcl/itcl and I'm trying to create a package.
The problem is that my files inside the package are dependent one on each other.

For example:

pkgIndex.tcl

```
package ifneeded test 1.0 [list ::apply {dir {

  package require Itcl
   namespace eval ::test {
       namespace export *
       variable version 1.0
  }
  source [file join $dir system.itcl]
  source [file join $dir subsystem.itcl]
  package provide test 1.0
}} $dir]
```

system.itcl

```
itcl::class ::test::system {
   ...
   private variable _subsystems ""
   ...
   constructor {} { lappend _subsystems [::test::subsystem #auto] }
   ...
}
```

subsystem.itcl

```
itcl::class ::test::subsystem {
   ...
   private variable data ""
   ...
   constructor {} { set data "new data" }
   ...
}
```

In this case, I should include subsystem.itcl file in system.itcl.
If I wasn't providing a package, I would use the source command but I read that when a package is provided you don't use source command instead there are other methods that will do the "include" operation.
The problem is that I couldn't find anywhere example / website that explain how to do it.

Comment: The way I do it is to source a single file from `pkgIndex.tcl` and if I need to split into more files I `source` or `package require` those files from the primary package file. This works fine for me, but it might not be best practice.

Comment: I did exactly the same , look on my answer below.   
by the way , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

(system and subsystem aren't packages in this scenario: see below)

(*DIR* is a directory in or added to `$auto_path`)

*DIR*/pkgIndex.tcl

```
package ifneeded test 1.0 [list source [file join $dir test.tcl]]
```

*DIR*/test.tcl

```
package require Itcl

set dir [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]
source [file join $dir subsystem.itcl]
source [file join $dir system.itcl]

namespace eval ::test {
       namespace export *
       variable version 1.0
}

package provide test $::test::version
```

*DIR*/system.itcl

```
itcl::class ::test::system {
   ...
   private variable _subsystems ""
   ...
   constructor {} { lappend _subsystems [::test::subsystem #auto] }
   ...
}
```

*DIR*/subsystem.itcl

```
itcl::class ::test::subsystem {
   ...
   private variable data ""
   ...
   constructor {} { set data "new data" }
   ...
}
```

Note that I don't use Itcl, so I don't know if I'm mangling it here.

The point of doing it like this is that I would want

1. the `pkgIndex.tcl` as simple as possible
2. the whole shebang as easy to load as possible (a single `package require` here)
3. the parts (system and subsystem) written as if they were part of `main.tcl`, just separated away in their own files for neatness
4. `main.tcl` expressing all information on how the parts of the code connect to each other

---

If system and subsystem should be packages, I would do:

(*DIR* is a directory in or added to `[::tcl::tm::path list]`)

*DIR*/test-1.0.tm

```
package require test::system

namespace eval ::test {
       namespace export *
       variable version 1.0
}
```

*DIR*/test/system-1.0.tm

```
package require Itcl
package require test::subsystem

itcl::class ::test::system {
   ...
   private variable _subsystems ""
   ...
   constructor {} { lappend _subsystems [::test::subsystem #auto] }
   ...
}
```

*DIR*/test/subsystem-1.0.tm

```
package require Itcl

itcl::class ::test::subsystem {
   ...
   private variable data ""
   ...
   constructor {} { set data "new data" }
   ...
}
```

Note that `package provide` isn't necessary here: it's done automagically when the module is loaded.

The point of doing it like this is that I would want

1. to avoid having to maintain an up-to-date `pkgIndex.tcl`
2. the parts as self-contained as possible
3. every part expressing what it needs for itself to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did this in the following way and it worked.

pkgIndex.tcl

```
package ifneeded test 1.0 [list source [file join $dir test.tcl]]
package ifneeded system 1.0 [list source [file join $dir system.itcl]]
package ifneeded subsystem 1.0 [list source [file join $dir subsystem.itcl]]
```

test.tcl

```
package require ::test::system
namespace eval ::test {
       namespace export *
       variable version 1.0
}
package provide test 1.0
```

system.itcl

```
package require ::test::subsystem
package require Itcl
itcl::class ::test::system {
   ...
   private variable _subsystems ""
   ...
   constructor {} { lappend _subsystems [::test::subsystem #auto] }
   ...
}    
package provide ::test::system 1.0
```

subsystem.itcl

```
package require Itcl
itcl::class ::test::subsystem {
   ...
   private variable data ""
   ...
   constructor {} { set data "new data" }
   ...
}
package provide ::test::subsystem 1.0
```

so every file is providing me a different package and requiring a different packages and pkgIndex file just making it to be possible by indeed command.

Comment: The `package ifneeded`s look a little suspicious, since the second `package ifneeded test 1.0` will _replace_ the first `package ifneeded test 1.0`…

Comment: Yes you are right, It was made by mistake.   
I will update this